# .Net Core 3.1 Worker Service, HTTP call fails when running with Docker

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker, service-worker

I am trying to develop my first Docker-enabled .Net Core 3.1 Worker Service. I am using the template for this in Visual Studio 2019. When debugging, I can run the code either as a console app, or as a Docker container. The first HTTP call my code makes works fine when running as a console app, but fails in Docker container mode with:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (No such host is known.)
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known.
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

The HTTP call is a HttpClient method:

```
var t = Task.Run(async () => { response = await httpClient.GetAsync(webApiUri); });
t.Wait();
```

What is going here? How can I remedy, please?
Thank you!
Eric

Comment: What's your `webApiUri` ?

Comment: A call to Azure AD:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startsWith(mailNickname%2C+%27I845917%27)&$select=AccountEnabled,givenName,surname,jobTitle,displayName,mailNickName,department,externalUserStateChangeDateTime,userPrincipalName,mail

Comment: Maybe you can try another url to check whether the problem still exist.

Comment: Good idea. But I ended up going with a different architecture on AWS. I developed some Lambda functions that use a SQS queue and DynamoDB tables. It's all working very well.